# Looking for a Flink RemoteStreamEnvironment sample project

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm looking for a sample project that will help me understand how to use the Flink RemoteStreamEnvironment api. Does anyone have a link to a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is no need to use either `RemoteStreamEnvironment` or `LocalStreamEnvironment`. Normally you can do

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
```

and the runtime will use either a local or remote stream execution environment, depending on how Flink is being launched (e.g., if from within an IDE you'll get a local mini-cluster, and with the CLI or REST api it's straightforward to submit a job to a cluster).

But if you want to use a `RemoteStreamEnvironment` directly, you can use one of the [StreamExecutionEnvironment#createRemoteEnvironment(...)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.html#createRemoteEnvironment-java.lang.String-int-org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration-java.lang.String...-) methods to create the remote execution environment, and then just use that env like you would any other to setup the job graph and execute the job.